# Backbone.js rendering multiple templates on the same view

Tags: templates, backbone.js, view

I'm just starting with Backbone.js. I'm building a Single Page Application and trying to figure out how I can handle this situation.

Depending on the view I'm rendering, I need to output multiple templates, meaning I have a wrapper that I use for the main template, and other 2 templates that go on other parts of the HTML.

I started by manually outputing the templates, but that got me thinking how correct that approach was, as it would require me to manually delete them whenever I navigate to other view.

The question is, **How can I effeciently render multiple templates in a single view (that are appended in different places) and still have control over the deletion on the entire view and undelegating its events?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd check out Addy Osmani's walkthrough for developing with backbone.js. 
http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

It walks through the example todo app, and then one more complicated one. What I think you want specifically is to use a framework such as Marionette.js to orchestrate and automate some of the event delegation and removal when you play with your views. If this is the case, skip to http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#marionettejs-backbone.marionette and read on about how marionette will help organizing views into regions and layouts as @NathanInMac said.

Answer (score 2):

You need a layout with a couple of regions.

Then put your sub-views in these regions.